# how to search two values using RowSorter JTable

Tags: java, search, jtable, row, rowsorter

when i select Class and Section from ComboBox then it will have to search Jtable for specific class and Section and show only those class and section?

[image]

Comment: Use custom TableModel with two List. In first keep all data, in second only data to show in Table (find result).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using additional comboboxes for searching, try using SwingBits Library for your code.

You can find the jar files [Here](https://github.com/eugener/oxbow/tree/master/maven/repository/org/oxbow/swing-bits/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT).

After that, add this line of code to your source after displaying all data in your jTable:

```
TableRowFilterSupport.forTable(jTable1).searchable(true).apply();
```

After that, you would be able to sort and filter data on runtime using left and right clicks of your mouse respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This is example with custom TableModel

**StudentTableModel.java**

```
public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel implements TableModel {
    private List<Student> data;
    private List<Student> filtredList;

    private Predicate<Student> predicate = student -> true;

    public List<Student> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<Student> data) {
        this.data = data;
        filter(predicate);
    }

    public void filter(Predicate<Student> predicate) {
        this.predicate = predicate;

        filtredList = data.stream()
                .filter(predicate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return "Title " + (column + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        if(filtredList == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return filtredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Student student = filtredList.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return rowIndex + 1;
            case 1: return student.getName();
            case 2: return student.getClassName();
            case 3: return student.getSectionName();

            default: return "N/A";
        }
    }
}
```

**MainFrame.java**

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private JTextField textField;
    private JComboBox<String> classComboBox, sectionComboBox;
    private JTable table;

    public MainFrame(String title) {
        super(title);
        creageGUI();
    }

    private void creageGUI() {
        List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Student("Name 1", "Class B", "1"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 2", "Class A", "1"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 3", "Class B", "3"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 4", "Class A", "1"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 5", "Class A", "2"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 6", "Class C", "1"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 7", "Class A", "3"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 8", "Class B", "4"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 9", "Class A", "1"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 10", "Class C", "2"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 11", "Class B", "1"));
        list.add(new Student("Name 12", "Class C", "1"));

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 480));

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                actionListener(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                actionListener(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                actionListener(null);
            }
        });

        JPanel searchPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 0));
        searchPanel.add(new JLabel("Search"));
        searchPanel.add(textField);

        classComboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[]{"Class A", "Class B", "Class C"});
        classComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        classComboBox.addActionListener(this::actionListener);

        sectionComboBox = new JComboBox<>(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"});
        sectionComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        sectionComboBox.addActionListener(this::actionListener);

        JPanel comboBoxPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 0));
        comboBoxPanel.add(new JLabel("Class"));
        comboBoxPanel.add(classComboBox);
        comboBoxPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));
        comboBoxPanel.add(new JLabel("Section"));
        comboBoxPanel.add(sectionComboBox);

        JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel();
        headerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(headerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        headerPanel.add(searchPanel);
        headerPanel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
        headerPanel.add(comboBoxPanel);

        StudentTableModel model = new StudentTableModel();
        model.setData(list);

        table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        JButton clearFilterButton = new JButton("Clear");
        clearFilterButton.addActionListener(event -> {
            textField.setText("");
            classComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
            sectionComboBox.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        });

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        bottomPanel.add(clearFilterButton);

        add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private void actionListener(ActionEvent event) {
        StudentTableModel model = (StudentTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.filter(student -> {
            String name = textField.getText();
            String className = (String) classComboBox.getSelectedItem();
            String sectionName = (String) sectionComboBox.getSelectedItem();

            if(!name.isEmpty() && !student.getName().contains(name)) {
                return false;
            }

            if(className != null && !student.getClassName().equals(className)) {
                return false;
            }

            if(sectionName != null && !student.getSectionName().equals(sectionName)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

and **Student.java**

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String className;
    private String sectionName;

    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String name, String className, String sectionName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.className = className;
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }

    public void setClassName(String className) {
        this.className = className;
    }

    public String getSectionName() {
        return sectionName;
    }

    public void setSectionName(String sectionName) {
        this.sectionName = sectionName;
    }
}
```